# Datatable rowCallback function after initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have the below working code for data table to set cell color based on condition.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // DataTable
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    /*
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: ['excel',{
extend: 'pdfHtml5',
orientation: 'landscape',
pageSize: 'LEGAL' }],
      "ordering": false,
       language: {
        search: "_INPUT_",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search All Data"
      } */
    rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
      console.log(row)
      if (data[12].split(';')[1] == "In Progress") {
        $(row).find('td:eq(11)').addClass('color')
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The above code works fine but if I remove the comments section which is to add export function, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing the same issue you're facing. I've created a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nka7djg1/), which is working nice and fine. The only thing I changed in your code is that I added a comma `(,)` before `rowCallback`, this way :

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: ['excel',{
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        orientation: 'landscape',
        pageSize: 'LEGAL' }],
        "ordering": false,
         language: {
          search: "_INPUT_",
          searchPlaceholder: "Search All Data"
        },
      rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
        console.log(row)
        if (data[12].split(';')[0] == "In Progress") {
          $(row).find('td:eq(11)').addClass('color')
        }
      }
});
```

and Plus, do recheck that the files related to jQuery datatable are same as the files I've added in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nka7djg1/) , there is a possibility that you've added a file twice or you might be using an older version of Jquery. If the issue still persists, edit your question and add your html + the files related to jquery that you've initialized.

Comment: Thanks bro, it works. Is it possible to export pdf with cell color ?

Comment: @user1650864 yes it is. All you've to do is to add a callback `customize` and define your criteria within it.  [refer](http://live.datatables.net/himajoxo/1/edit)